# Slide toggle back and forth with jquery ui

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am using the Jquery UI to slide content left and then slide other content at the same time to take the first content's place. It works as intended the first time I press "Change username". However, when I want to reverse the `slideToggle`, my new content is pushing down the first content, which causes the content to slide then pop up. How can I avoid this?

I don't want the image to slide as well. It should stay in its place.

`position: absolute` is not an option either.

```js
$("#cu").click(function(){
  $(".profileBox").toggle('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 500);
  $("#changeName").toggle('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 500);
  $("#backer").toggle('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 500);
});
$("#backer").click(function(){
  $("#changeName").toggle('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 500);
  $("#backer").toggle('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 500);
  $(".profileBox").toggle('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 500);

});
```

```css
#profile {
width: 75%;
max-width: 400px;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(37, 76, 91, 1);
position: fixed;
top: 0;
display: none;
right: 0;
}
#backer {
font-size: min(3.0vw, 22px);
position: absolute;
margin: 5px;
width: 100%;
display: none;
}
.superFlex, .profileBox {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
}
.usercon, #changeName {
width: 100%;
height: 40px;
display: flex;
background-color: #4E748B;
font-size: 14px;
margin-top: 2px;
cursor: pointer;
}
.profileBox{
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="profile" style="display: block;">
  <i id="backer" class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></i>
    <div class="superFlex">
    <div class="first">
      <img src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSStq.png?s=256&g=1" height = "100">       
      <p style="margin:0;">TEXT</p>
    </div>
    <form id="changeName" class="swiped" style="display: none;">
      <p class="general">Username</p>
        </form> 
    <div class="profileBox" style="">   
      <p class="general">Account settings</p>
          <div class="usercon" id="cu"><p>Change username</p></div>
      </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is absolute positioning "not an option"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [jQuery UI's .toggle method](https://jqueryui.com/toggle/) is the wrong tool for this job. `.toggle()` is for showing/hiding a single element, not for shifting cells of content in a grid to the left or right.

I think the correct conceptual model for this is to imagine a slider box that is twice the width of viewport. It contains two slides, side-by-side, each half the width of the slider (or exactly the same width as the viewport). Only one slide is visible at a time. The navigation buttons will change the `margin-left` property of the slider so that either the first or second slide is in view.

This would require re-working the existing HTML structure somewhat. For example, the `#backer` arrow would need to go inside of the second slide. We could use a negative `margin-top` to get to display in roughly the same place you had it originally.

We would also need to add `overflow: hidden` to the container of the slider - in this case, `.superFlex` - so that the slide that is out-of-view is unseen.

The resultant code looks like:

```js
$('#cu').click(function() {
  $('#Slider').animate({
    marginLeft: '-100%'
  });
});

$('#backer').click(function() {
  $('#Slider').animate({
    marginLeft: '0'
  });
});
```

```css
#profile {
  width: 75%;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(37, 76, 91, 1);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  right: 0;
}

#backer {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: min(3.0vw, 22px);
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: -155px;
}

.superFlex,
.profileBox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.usercon,
#changeName {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #4E748B;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.profileBox {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  align-self: flex-start;
  display:flex;
  margin-left: 0;
  width: 200%;
}

.slide {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="profile" style="display: block;">
  <div class="superFlex" style="overflow:hidden;">
    <div class="first">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSStq.png?s=256&g=1" height="100">
      <p style="margin:0;">TEXT</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="slider" id="Slider">
      <div class="slide">
        <div class="profileBox">
          <p class="general">Account settings</p>
          <div class="usercon" id="cu">
            <p>Change username</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <form id="changeName" class="swiped">
          <p class="general">Username</p>
        </form>
        <i id="backer" class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats another approach to my problem, makes sense to avoid toggle and just hide the element. Thanks for your thoughts and answer =)